# VB6: How to make inet asynchronous?

Tags: vb6

my vb6 code currently uses the code below for `inet` control to retrive data. But it make my progarm slow because of the `loop` as it make its synchronous. Hoe can i make `inet` asynchronous?

> ```
>     HTML = Inet(Index).GetChunk(1024)
>     Do Until Buffer = Empty
>       Buffer = Inet(Index).GetChunk(1024)
>       HTML = HTML & HTML
>     Loop
> ```

Comment: found solution by adding the code :     buffer = buffer & Inet1.GetChunk(1024)

Comment: Have you tried DoEvents?

Comment: The code above is going to have HTML equal to the first chunk obtained being repeated as many times as the loop iterated.